# Getting cross-thread violation when installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am running ruby 1.9.2 p180 using rvm.

I tried to install rails:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

And I got this:

```
Successfully installed activerecord-3.1.3
Successfully installed activeresource-3.1.3
Successfully installed mail-2.3.0
Successfully installed actionmailer-3.1.3
Successfully installed rack-ssl-1.3.2
Successfully installed rdoc-3.12
Successfully installed railties-3.1.3
Successfully installed rails-3.1.3
22 gems installed
[BUG] cross-thread violation on rb_gc()
(null)
```

I was using 1.8.7 all this time, but wanted to try using 1.9.2 as that is where things seem to be moving and ran into this bug.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

See the section "Bus Error / Segfault" in [Troubleshooting RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/support/troubleshooting/):

> In every case of this I have seen thus far it has always ended up being that a ruby gem/library with C extensions was compiled against a different ruby and/or architecture than the one that is trying to load it. Try uninstalling & reinstalling gems with C extensions that your application uses to hunt this buggar down.

No guarantees that this is the problem, but ensure that all of your gems were compiled for the architecture you are running on (64-bit vs. 32-bit, for example).  You didn't mention the platform/architecture in your post.  If you are running OSX, see [OSX, RubyGems and cross-thread violations in rb_gc](http://blog.ubrio.us/nix/osx-rubygems-and-cross-thread-violations-in-rb_gc/), as well.  Chances are you are picking up some of the 1.8.7 gems.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you run sudo gem with RVM?
Have you tried:

> rvm use rails-1.9.2-p180
>
> gem install rails

under the folder you are creating the app you can also create a .rvmrc file with the ruby version you are running so everytime you ge into the folder you it would switch to the version set in the .rvmrc

sample:

> rvm ruby-1.9.2-p180@myapp